# Trying to clothe a character

Tags: cloth-simulation, soft-body

I've been following online tutorials as best I can to try and put a shirt on my character.

For some reason instead of the shirt forming around the body, it transforms into a mass of jagged edges and grows.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

I don't want to shrink wrap the shirt onto her as she's not meant to be sexy at all. I'd rather the shirt cover her up and be a little baggy.

I want to move on to doing a skirt for her too, so imagine the same issues will arise. Was planning to extrude a circle around her waist and add a cloth modifier to it.

Here's a link to the file if it's easier to just take a look. I'm pulling my hair out. Thanks.

[blender file](https://we.tl/t-oRwhOnzrVc)

Comment: have you tried making the shirt low-poly while you're simulating the cloth and then using subdivision surface modifier after the fact?

Comment: No. But it's fairly low poly anyway. Doesn't it need a decent number of vertices to bend properly?